# Install new thunderbird 68 under ubuntu that have older one in repository

Tags: thunderbird

Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) has last 60.8.0 thunderbird version.
If like me, you want already have the just fresh v68.0 release…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: it doesn't overwrite v60.8 you already have!

You can download it on [official thunderbird website](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/)
Then extract it, for example in */home/$USER/Downloads/*
If you launch *thunderbird* runable file (from nautilus), it runs but doesn't find your *profil* so, I launched it from terminal:

```
cd /home/$USER/Downloads/thunderbird
./thunderbird
```

if your profil are not founded, launched one time with:

```
./thunderbird -P
```

and select *default*

To add icon launcher:
Create file like:
/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/tb68.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Thunderbird-68
Icon=thunderbird
Exec="/home/$USER/Downloads/thunderbird-68/thunderbird"
Comment=last TB version
Categories=Application;Network;Email;
Terminal=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Compose;Contacts
```

then click "show all applications" launcher or *super*, type "tb", the new launcher should appears, right-click on it and select add in your favorites.
Perhaps you will need to replace $USER with your account name.

EDIT : To TB-68 to 78, I just accepted download link which is open when TB starts !

---

As my point of view, it is ok to wait that v68 are in official repository.
In other case it should be probably better to use [snap](https://snapcraft.io/thunderbird) (not available yet) or [flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) solution.

Comment: Issue with this method is that there is no laucher icon in your application menu for the new version. You may want to add how to do that.

Comment: @vanadium Your're right, it's done right now!

Comment: It is fine to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the current Linux version of thunderbird,
https://download.mozilla.org/?product=thunderbird-68.1.0-SSL&os=linux64&lang=en-US
e.g. "thunderbird-68.1.0.tar.bz2" and extract it as root into
/usr/lib/
by using

```
user@sh~$: sudo tar -C /usr/lib/ -xjvpf ~/Downloads/thunderbird-68.1.0.tar.bz2
```

it worked for me under Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Since I am using thunderbird on Mac, Windows and Linux in parallel, I prefer having it on the same version.

Note: This might be overwritten if an official update package for thunderbird will be installed from ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will work with Ubuntu, but worked great with Mint.

To put an icon on the Desktop, you can also create a launcher for the desktop by right clicking the desktop:

1. Select *Create a new launcher here …*.
2. Put in the name you want to appear on the launcher in the top box.
3. Browse to the folder and program starting file.
4. Click *OK*

This should create a launcher on the desktop.

Once the icon appears on the Desktop, to change the icon, right click on the icon and select *Properties*.  When that window appears, left click on the icon and select one of the headings on the left to look through for a more meaningful icon.

Click on it and click *Select*.  In this case under *Applications*, I found *Thunderbird – Old* and that worked fine.

Comment: thank for this info, but take into account that the question is not about create a shortcut… and not about mint, but I know when you begin to contribute, you can't add comment!